# Variable taking variable value from a function return

Tags: c

i have a function that reads content of a file more exactly the first line, measures the length of what it finds and returns it. Initially the function printed what it read but i modify it to "return buffer"

here is my function:

```
char *get_process() {
    int len = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
        while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if (c == '\n') {
                break;
            }
            len++;
    buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), len, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return buffer;
}
```

the content of input.txt is something like /etc/config.conf

now my problem is that i want to do is assign what this function returns to a variable that i use in main() function.

what i did i have added to my main function:

char *PID = get_process();

But i have the following error on compilation:
**:760: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast**

I'm doing something wrong of course like always.
But what is it?

Comment: C or C++? You can't program in both languages, please pick the one you're actually program in.

Comment: Most likely you didn't declare the signature of `get_process` somewhere before the main function (which could be via a header file).

Comment: Please read the description of the tags that you applied, C and C++ are mutually exclusive. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, please reduce the code to a [mcve].

Comment: The complete code to be pasted in order to be reproduce is about 5000 lines.

Comment: `return 1;` um.... interesting choice of return value for a function promising a return result of type `char *` . Something wrong with `NULL` and having the caller check for that?

Comment: Also your `EOF` check is flawed since `EOF` is an ***`int`*** value and [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int` just for that reason.

Comment: You're not supposed to post the whole code. You need to extract the relevant parts into a [mcve], who's only purpose is to serve as example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `fp==NULL` then your function will `return 1;`. Thats why you are getting this warning. Instead you can `return NULL;` or `return nullptr;` to indicate that something went wrong.

[EDIT]
If your code added in the question is exactly what you have written in your program, then you have one more problem, as your while loop closing brace is not placed

Comment: fixed with return NULL but now a new error popup: :In function `get_process': :4854: parse error at end of input

Comment: @JerichoST I think thats because you have forgot the closing } of your while loop

Comment: done i was missing a } at the end of get_process function. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @JerichoST No problem

Comment: @JerichoST If my answer is accepted please select it as accepted)